# Question about meaning of "it's nice" in this passage. Could you use the phrase in very similar situations, so that I can understand its meaning

Tags: expressions

> So today we want to talk about the subject of first time driving tips. What is important to learn when we first start our driving? And I feel that the most important thing is speed control. We want to have the ability to accelerate and to brake in a nice, calm, smooth manner. So the first time we get in the car, we want to be able to get a feel for the accelerator. We want to realize that you don’t have to press too hard on that accelerator to get that car to start to accelerate. It’s a nice, smooth touch on the accelerator, and the same thing with the brake. We want to have a nice, easy touch on the brake so that we can stop the car and accelerate the car in a nice, smooth manner.
>
> The other thing is our hand position when we’re driving. **It’s nice**, soft hands are very important in learning to drive. We don’t want a death grip on that wheel. We want nice, soft hands, like pretty much anything that you do in sports, your hands have to be nice and soft. If your hands are soft and you’re not real tense, you’ll find that you have the ability to steer a car much, much better.

When the coach here is saying **it's nice**, what does he mean by saying that? Might it be something else written wrongly in the transcript.  like its nice rather than it's nice ?

Comment: The comma should probably have been a period. *Nice* is pretty much the equivalent of *good* in general or maybe *comfortable* in this particular sentence.

Comment: Actually I think a colon would be the best punctuation. But don't worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a colloquial expression meaning "gentle, gently, not at all aggressive(ly)" as in:

**Get a nice soft grip on the steering wheel.**

**And take it nice and easy. Don't jam your foot down on the accelerator.**

It's nice = It is nice.

If the transcript is correct, the coach seems to have changed his mind about the syntax midway. It should read:

It's nice, soft hands *that* are very important when learning to drive.

or

*It's nice, soft hands that we want when learning to drive.*

or

*Nice, soft hands are very important when learning to drive.*

In other words:

It is important to keep a gentle grip on the wheel.

Comment: I agree with TRomano.  OP, you are confused because the sentence, as written, doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence "It’s nice, soft hands are very important in learning to drive"  makes no sense grammatically and really the content of the sentence doesn't make any sense to me. It is an example of terrible English